# How to connect SpagoBI to Apache Hadoop (hdfs)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, spagobi

I have a huge data in Hadoop (HDFS). How can i connect SpagoBI with HDFS to configure a Data Source. IN SpagoBI I cannot find any option for HDFS Storage in Dialect Drop down on Add Data Source Page.

Is there a way to use HDFS Data in SpagoBI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect SpagoBI to Hive tables.

so first if your data is structured , then transfer all data to hive tables or simply create hive external table on top of your data.

then through HiveServer2 driver you can connect .

you have to put hive jdbc jar and other common jar file manually in your spagoBI lib directory.

your spagoBI connection properties should look something like this:

provide credentials to connect with hive given below:-

URL : jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/xyz

Driver: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Comment: URL : jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/xyz - Here xyz is the name of the database ?

Comment: yes xyz is the name of database. apologies for late reply. was out of office